# SharePoint "Working on it" for a given site collection

Tags: 2013, site-collection, performance

I have about 30 `site collections` in `SharePoint 2013` on premises  environment. All the sites are fine except a Sales Site which show

> "Working on it"

for about 4/5 seconds.

The landing page of the Sales Site is blank and nothing on it so I can rule out bad webpart or what have you.

Where else should I look?

Comment: Please let me know if I need to include more specific details.

Comment: Open up developer tools (F12) and go to the site.  Post in your question what errors pop up in the console.

Comment: I deactivated "Minimal Download Strategy" and now I don't see "Working on it" but slowness is still there (5 to 10 seconds) to load the page. The database is only 400 MB.

Comment: Do an iis reset.. It solves the problem most of the tone

Answer (score 0):

To improve the SharePoint performance, you can try the following solutions:


- Stop Distributed cache service.
  
- Move some web parts to another page if there are too many.
  
- Check if there are lists or libraries having too many items.
  
- Check if content databases grows up to SQL’s limit.

Here is a link with more possible causes and corresponding solutions:
http://davidlozzi.com/2013/01/16/my-users-dont-like-sharepoint-because-it-is-too-slow/

Comment: Could it be "Mega Menu"? because when I don't have mega menu the sites are somewhat faster.